# Incorrect migration of an object from Firebase to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, migration, json, firebase

I am in the process of migrating a database from Firebase to MongoDB and am facing a problem. Here is such an object I have stored in the FB:

```js
"logs": {
    "2021-05-24": {
        "124109": {
            "foo": "text",
            "bar": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

When I import it into Mongo (through the Mongo compass as a JSON object) it is inserted in this form:

```js
"logs": {
    "2021-05-24": [
        null,
        null,
        ... # overall 124109 nulls here
        null,
        {
            "foo": "text",
            "bar": "text"
        }
    ]
}
```

As I can see, it reads the key of the nested object as the number of real array objects. How can I correctly migrate an object of this type in mongo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I put the source data in upper codeblock, which contain the object `"124109": { ... }`, but after importing to mongo it transforming into array `[ ]`, my question is how to fix it

Comment: Explain the process you had used - in detail - how you have imported into MongoDB Noted the mention of Compass, that is not the complete process you are trying.

Comment: @prasad_ i exported db from firebase to json file, next I opened the mongodb compass, opened the collection, pressed import via json file and imported

Comment: What does the exported json look like?

Comment: @prasad_ exported json look like my first codeblock in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input JSON (`input.json`):

```
{
  "logs": {
    "2021-05-24": {
        "124109": {
            "foo": "text",
            "bar": "text"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You can import using the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) command-line tool. This will import into the MongoDB collection correctly. For example, from the OS command prompt:

```
mongoimport --db=test --collection=test --file=input.json
```

Note the "input.json" file needs to be in the same directory from where you are executing the command (or specify full path).

The resulting document looked like this, with the MongoDB created `_id` field:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("613f25725ed44abe4b8957ef"),
        "logs" : {
                "2021-05-24" : {
                        "124109" : {
                                "foo" : "text",
                                "bar" : "text"
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I had tried the same import using the MongoDB Compass v1.21.2 inot MongoDB v4.2.8 database - and I see the same problem as you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, indeed, if I import the data in any other way, except through Mongo Compass, everything works (checked in `pymongo`). Apparently there is some problem in Mongo Compass import service.